# Convert binary content of pdf file in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, androidpdfviewer

I am getting a response from the server which starts from `%PDF-1.7`. I believe that it is a base64 string(correct if I am wrong). Now while decoding the data using kotlin I am getting an error.What I want to achieve is I want to parse the response and open it into a pdfviewer.Help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: No base64 but just the pdf document. There is nothing to decode.

Comment: Use a byte reader/writer instead of character reader/writer and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all those who are still stuck in this.I have cracked this in the below way

Summary before I start

1. I have used volley string request.
2. I have used third party library
   `implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2`

> Layout file

```
 <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfViewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

> Kotlin code

```
 override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<String?>? {
                val data = response.data
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
            }
```

and then in your response listener

```
 binding?.pdfViewer?.fromBytes(data)?.load()
```

Happy coding.